# PostgreSQL - Find equality of two values, both of which can be NULL

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, `NULL` is not considered equal to anything, so `NULL = NULL` returns `false`. I'm writing a query in which one of my `WHERE` conditions checks the equality of two values. If both values are `NULL` I want that to return `true` as any other value comparison. Currently I do:

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE baz = qux
   OR (baz IS NULL AND qux IS NULL);
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the null safe equality comparison `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`:

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE baz IS NOT DISTINCT FROM qux;
```

Here is a brief demo showing that records get returned when the two sides of `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` are both the same non `NULL` value, or both are `NULL`:

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the help! For anybody else's reference, this can be found in the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-comparison.html)